# Javascript - Dynamic grid fancy delete option

Tags: javascript

I have an AJAX dynamic grid and when i want to delete an item i click a link (`href='javascript:void(0)'`) and the item's gone. That's no problem. What the problem is I don't want the item to simply disappear, I want to add a kind of special effect, like to make the item shrink, and those items around it to gradually take its place. Maybe like Digg, when you bury stuff there. I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$("selector").slideUp("slow", function () {
    $(this).remove(); 
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Lookup jquery effects:

http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/